# Android release build crashes at installation

Tags: android, react-native

The app works fine while debugging but release build instantly crashes at launch. Here's the adb logcat stack trace:

[image]

It seems a `NameNotFoundException` is being thrown here for the package `com.vynilla`, which is strange because its the package name/application ID of my app.

Here's the AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.vynilla">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any idea where the problem might be?

**UPDATE**:

I couldn't figure out the problem and had to move my source to a new project. I suppose that's the only way to fix these vague bugs for now.

Comment: Would you mind posting your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Dinesh updated the question with AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Kill all node instance before build.
if you have index.js, use this command to bundle.

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js -- 
bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest 
android/app/src/main/res
```

Create release apk:

```
cd android/
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

generated apk location is :

```
app/build/outputs/apk/
```

Comment: The first command doesn't work: "bundle-output is not recognized as an internal or external command".
The second one just generates an apk which also crashes upon installation.

Comment: have you index.js or index.android.js in project root ?

Comment: I have an index.js